# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Double' type is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

When executing the following query, I get the error:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the
>   'System.Double' type is not valid.

```
var data = ctx.tblTO
                   .Where(m => m.Id == Id)
                   .GroupBy(m => m.EmployeeId)
                   .Select(m => new
                   {
                       workDay = m.Sum(k => k.WorkDay),
                       onDutyDay = m.Sum(k => k.OnDutyDay),
                       holiDay = m.Sum(k => k.Holiday)
                   })
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

The datatype of `WorkDay`, `OnDutyDay` and `Holiday` is `double`. There is no `Int32` here, so why do I get this error?

How can I solve this error?

```
public class TO
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }           
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public double WorkDay { get; set; }
    public double OnDutyDay { get; set; }
    public double Holiday { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the `tblTO` model, please?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I think the data type of the columns inside your database table is `Int32` but your data model has `double`. You need to change the data types of your data models to `int`. By `materialized` it means the type it got when it ran the query on the database.

Comment: That's right. I changed the database `datatype` from `int` to `float`. Now Working Fine.

Comment: @Anup, i have this issue. But in my Database i have float and in my model i have float too. How can I do to solve this issue? This is error message: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Single' type to the 'System.Double' type is not valid.'`

Comment: @pnet, `float` in sql holds 8 bytes of data while `float` in the .net world holds 4 bytes of data. So you could use `double` datatype in your code or you could use `real` datatype on your db.

Comment: As a point to note. This error can also occur when the return types from the db do not match the types of the .net fields it is being loaded into. I.e. if you are trying to load the result into an existing class and the types do not match.

Comment: I wish the exception details in c# would be expanded as to indicate the fields which are causing problems like this. Related would be in object ref nullable errors, when it's difficult to tell which object is null!

Answer (score 3):

First make sure your model and table column  data type are same.

Try to change your query to this.

```
var data = ctx.tblTO
           .Where(m => m.Id == Id)
           .GroupBy(m => m.EmployeeId)
           .Select(m => new
           {
               workDay = m.Select(k => k.WorkDay).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
               onDutyDay = m.Select(k => k.OnDutyDay).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
               holiDay = m.Select(k => k.Holiday).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()
           })
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

If the collection is empty, it will return one element with the value of 0 and then the sum will be applied.

Comment: I have this issue, but my code do not accept ` MyProperty = m.Select(....)`. How can I do? The message is: Liberacao do not contain a definition to `Select`...

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other answers, I got another scenario where I faced the same error. Which is, In our stored procedure a `bigint` was being casted to a decimal and on `C#` the same thing was being casted to int64. See:

```
SELECT Cast(@Request_Id as decimal) AS RetValue
```

What I did was changed the query to this:

```
SELECT @Request_Id AS RetValue
```

So, I removed the extra casting and the issue was gone. Somehow, it was maybe raising some sort of arithmetic exceptions but not quite sure yet. Will Update soon if I get to know the exact reason.

PS: My `@Request_Id` variable is of type `bigint`.

```
DECLARE @Request_Id bigint = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I was calling a `stored procedure` from EF 6 of which I wrote a poco, but I didn't write the sproc.  I needed to look at all the tables that had field returning data types. and then change my Poco from a int to boolean.

```
public Boolean Active { get; set; }
```