# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Int64' type is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

On executing following query, I get the error :-

```
public MioLMOrderConfirmAddress GetAddress(long headerId,int addressCategory)
    {
        using (var c = new TenantEntities(_tenantConString))
        {
            var data =
                c.MioLMOrderConfirmAddresses.FirstOrDefault(
                    x => x.MioLMOrderConfirmHeaderId == headerId && x.AddressCategoryId == addressCategory);
            return data;
        }
    }
```

**Error :**

> Additional information: The specified cast from a materialized
>   'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Int64' type is not valid.

My Model class is here

```
public partial class MioLMOrderConfirmAddress
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long MioLMOrderConfirmHeaderId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> MioLMOrderConfirmLineId { get; set; }
    public int AddressCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string FullAddress { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalStreetName { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string PostalZone { get; set; }
    public string CountrySubEntity { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string BuildingNumber { get; set; }
    public string AddressFormatCode { get; set; }
    public string AddressTypeCode { get; set; }
    public string BlockName { get; set; }
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }
    public string CitySubDivisionName { get; set; }
}
```

How to solve this error?

This is the screenshot of MioLMOrderConfirmAddress table
[MioLMOrderConfirmAddress Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkf6l.png)

Comment: Try `x => x.MioLMOrderConfirmHeaderId == Convert.ToInt64(headerId)` or re-declare `headerId` parameter as `long`

Comment: Is `MioLMOrderConfirmHeaderId ` an `int` or is `AddressCategoryId` a `bigint` in the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264382/linq-the-specified-cast-from-a-materialized-system-int32-type-to-the-system

Comment: @Tim 'MioLMOrderConfirmHeaderId  is 'bigint' and 'AddressCategoryId ' is 'int'

Comment: Could you show screenshot or attach snippet from MioLMOrderConfirmAddress  table in database?

Comment: I think the problem is with your datatype in model, the `MioLMOrderConfirmLineId` should be  `Nullable<int>` instead. Ofcourse if database type is `int`.

Comment: The exception may be thrown due to any of the other properties. Please post the table schema and the *full* exception, including its call stack. This will show where the exception actually occurred. You can get the full exception with `Exception.ToString()`. At the very least post the database types of the numeric properties - one of them probably isn't `bigint`, or it is the result of some expression that returns `int`

Answer (score 0):

Answer for code-first users...

If you can hold your values inside an "int", you can work around this problem by converting your properties from long to int (and from long? to int?).

Then, tell that your fields are in fact "bigint" or "decimal" in your OnModelCreating method:

```
modelBuilder
    .Properties()
    .Where(p => p.Name.EndsWith("Id"))
    .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("bigint"));
```

This works if your database columns are either int, bigint or decimal.

Hope this helps someone else with this issue