# Getting a casting error for no visible reason

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have this piece of code that's been throwing a casting error, and I have no idea why after playing with it for half an hour.  This is the piece of code:

```
var zips = DB.Get<Partner_to_ZipCode>()
                .AsQueryable()
                .Include(i => i.Partner)
                .Where(w => w.Partner.Id == id)
                .Select(s => s.ZipCode)
                .ToArray();
```

It's pointing to line 146 of the controller, which is this linq query right here.  "Partner.Id" is an integer as is "id", and ZipCode is a string.  I have no idea what's going on here. I've tried commenting out pieces of code, casting variables, changing the array from a generic to a specific type, none of it did anything.  Any help would be appreciated.

The error message is:

> {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"**The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.**","exceptionType":"**System.InvalidOperationException**","stackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetColumnValueWithErrorHandling[TColumn](Int32 ordinal)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at PMP.MVC.Controllers.PartnerController.GetTasks(Int32 id) in c:\\Users\\maran\\OneDrive\\Documents\\RF\\main\\src\\PMP.MVC\\PMP.MVC\\Controllers\\PartnerController.cs:line 146\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

Comment: Mismatch between database column types and entity types?

Comment: Assign each Linq chain to an individual variable/Linq.Function() to add transparency into what's going on where.

Comment: might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264382/linq-the-specified-cast-from-a-materialized-system-int32-type-to-the-system

Comment: .Where(w => w.Partner.Id == id) maybe there you compare int to string

Comment: Both Ids are integers, the entity and db types match.  I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried checking _all_ the columns and properties on all of the objects are the data-types you expect? Perhaps the FK property used in the relationship is not the string/int it is expected to be?

Comment: ok, after digging through every single part of the db I finally found something that conflicted.  Thank you guys.

Comment: What is the type of `ZipCode` column in the database table? The exception indicates that it's a `int` while the class expects `string`.

Answer (score 0):

one of these two might work:

```
.Where(w => w.Partner.Id.ToString() == id)

.Where(w => w.Partner.Id == id.ToString())
```

one of those: local variable "id" or w.Partner.Id is a string and the other is a int.
It is safer to cast int to string than other way, because string might contain something else than numbers and you'll need to handle that case.

Comment: If that was the case, OP would get compile time error, not runtime exception.

Comment: in loop during searching collection mapped from database? Maybie not :) During compilation values of that collection are unknown. Otherwise I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var zips = DB.Get<Partner_to_ZipCode>()
.AsQueryable()
.Include(i => i.Partner)
.Where(w => w.Partner.Id.ToString() == id) // or (w => w.Partner.Id == int.Parse(id)) if id is an integer
.Select(s => s.ZipCode)
.ToArray();
```